# Vertically center text in text input in IE9 + IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, css, input

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/D7v2Y/

In firefox/webkit this works great. The text is centered. Not in IE10 or IE9

```
input {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

What's goin' on here and how do I get the text input to display "correctly" with the text vertically centered in IE?

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to reconcile the `padding` and `line-height`. With `box-sizing: border-box`, they are essentially fighting for the same real estate.

In other words, you are saying "fit 50px of line height into 50px of total vertical space, but also pad it by 20px".

A simple solution is to reduce the `line-height` so that `padding` * 2 + `line-height` = 50px. Or, if you want more `line-height`, reduce the padding. If you want to keep the same `line-height` *and* padding, increase the height to 70px.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/D7v2Y/11/

```
input {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: you posted the exact same code as OP. Shouldn't it be `line-height: 30px;` according to your remarks?

Comment: This answer was very, very helpful. Understanding the relationship between line-height and padding + margin enabled me to fix in 2 minutes what I couldn't resolve in 2 hours.

Answer (score 2):

I added a font-size and that seem to do the trick:

```
input {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 1.0;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

A bit odd... but it seems to be one way of doing it.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Y2rd4/

**Box Sizing**

I noticed that the box-sizing property computes a different height in IE10/9 compared to Firefox.  If you omit that property, the input field renders more similarly.

Answer (score -2):

the padding is breaking it in IE8, god only knows why....

just remove the padding